# NPM package with dependencies for global installation only?

Tags: npm-install

If an NPM package is designed both as a global command and as a dependency for other applications / packages, may I specify its dependencies for different installation cases?

[#zh-CN](https://github.com/YounGoat/articles/blob/master/2021/zh-CN.md) 假设一个 NPM 包既可作为全局命令，也可以作为其他应用程序或包的依赖项。那么，在 package.json 中是否可以为不同的安装模式指定不同的依赖项？

E.g., package **mypkg** depends on package **foo** when it runs as a global command. However, **foo** is unnecessary when **mypkg** is installed and used as a dependency for other applications / packages. How to prevent **foo** installed when `-g` | `--global` option is absent?

[#zh-CN](https://github.com/YounGoat/articles/blob/master/2021/zh-CN.md) 例如，**mypkg** 作为全局命令运行时，需要依赖 **foo**；但如果它仅作为其他应用程序或包的依赖项，则并不依赖 **foo**。怎样可以在非全局安装模式下，阻止安装 **foo**？

In another word, I mean
[#zh-CN](https://github.com/YounGoat/articles/blob/master/2021/zh-CN.md) 换句话说，我的意思是

```sh
# Please DO NOT install **foo**.
npm install mypkg

# Please DO install **foo**.
npm install --global mypkg
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is, install any package globally only if you require it. Whenever a package or project requires another package to run as a dependency, then install it as a dependency. This way, whenever anyone installs the package and tries running it through an npm script, the package will run fine, because you have specified the correct version and package that has to be installed in order for the script to run without any errors.

Comment: Maybe my question is ambiguous. It is assumed that I am the owner of package __mypkg__, not a developer who wants to make use of this package.